# Change text if div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9djdtaob/) changes text of `#more` depending on the visibility of `#extra`:

```
<style>
#extra{
  display: none;
}
</style>

<a href="#" id="more">More about us</a>
<div id="extra">Some Text</div>

<script>
$('#more').click(function() {        
    if ($('#extra').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).text('Less about us');
    } else {
        $(this).text('More about us');
    }

    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');   
});
</script>
```

This works fine. However, it does not work anymore if I put the `slideToggle()` above the if-statement like this (see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhmj89td/)):

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast');

    if ($('#extra').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).text('More about us');         
    } else {         
        $(this).text('Less about us');
    }
});
```

In this example, the text will remain "More about us" no matter if `#extra` is hidden or not. Why?

Comment: The second doesn't work because the if is evaluated before the slideToggle is done. And in the first example, don't you want `if(!$('#extra').is(':visible')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code get's executed one line at a time, so by the time you enter the if, the slideToggle isn't finished so the element is visible.

You should put the if statement inside the slideToggle's complete callback http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

```
$('#more').click(function() {
  var _this = this;
  $('#extra').slideToggle('fast', function() {
    if($(this).is(':visible')) {
      $(_this).text('Less about us');
    }
    else {
      $(_this).text('More about us');
    }
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhmj89td/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the animation isn't done before you check the visibility. A cleaner solution would be this:

```
var visible = false;
$('#more').click(function() {
  visible = !visible;

  if (visible) $('#extra').slideDown();
  else $('#extra').slideUp();

  $(this).text(visible ? 'Less about us' : 'More about us');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhmj89td/2/)

This way you don't have to check the actual visibility of the element. You could use a callback to execute the code after the animation has completed, but that could cause an unwanted delay.